# Encoding *.h264 to *.ts in ffmpeg failure

Tags: ffmpeg, transport-stream

I want to encode an h.264 elementarystream to a transportstream with ffmpeg. 
The command `ffmpeg -i in.264 -c copy out.ts` gives me a *ts file, but it is not decodable from VCL and it is also 0kb. Is there an non-cost alternative?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Ok, the problem is not ffmpeg here, the h.264 es is here the problem. The timestamps are not properly set. SPS is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mp4box or ffmpeg to mux to MP4 first, and then remux that to TS.

Comment: Why? How does this differ from remuxing from elemental to TS?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack - ffmpeg's TS muxer does not assign timestamps if incoming first packet has NOPTS, but the MP4 muxer does (it sets pts to dts value). This is generally fine but with streams having B-frames pyramid, this will distort presentation order, so mp4box is preferred.